# Check if GPG/PGP public key is valid

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

Through a web interface I'm trying to check if a given public key is valid or not. The bash command `gpg --import key.pub` returns `import successful/failed` based on the given key, but I don't want to use `$data = system("/usr/bin/gpg --import $key)` for my own security concerns. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've done a little debugging and this is what I've found:

nginx daemon was running under `nginx:nginx`, no home dir, nologin shell

When I executed `sudo -u nginx php -r "echo system("gpg -k");"`

I got `/home/nginx/.gnupg: directory does not exist!`

So I've executed the following:

`mkdir -p /home/nginx/.gnupg; chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx/`

Then, to test if works:

`sudo -u nginx php -r "echo system("gpg --homedir /home/nginx/.gnupg --dry-run --batch --import key.pub");`

and I've got output!

Answer (score 0):

Is installing extension an option for you? Because you can use combination of [gnupg_import()](http://docs.php.net/gnupg_import) and [gnupg_keyinfo()](http://docs.php.net/gnupg_keyinfo) function from [PECL/gnupg](http://pecl.php.net/package/gnupg) extension.

`gnupg_keyinfo()` returns array of properties and there are various keys which would be useful in this case. see: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/gnupg/trunk/gnupg.c?revision=330955&view=markup#l662