# Check if an entered public key is a valid OpenPGP key

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, gnupg, privacy, pgp

I'm using the GnuPG class from PHP. I'm not having any problem importing valid public key but if I try to import something random like "test" which obviously isn't a public key, I'm getting error 502 bad gateway. I saw into PHP documentation that `gnupg_keyinfo` shows information introducing a name stored in the keyring. I searched around the internet and I didn't find a way to check if an entered public key is in the right format or not.
I'm using the following piece of code:

```
<?php
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/kevin/.gnupg');
$gpg = '/usr/bin/gpg';
$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

if(isset($_POST['2fa'])){
    try {
      $key = $_POST['new_pgp'];
      $retVal = $gpg->import($key);
      echo $retVal['imported'] . ' key(s) imported.';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="pgp.php" method="post">
<textarea name="new_pgp"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="2fa" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP check if GPG/PGP public key is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498165/php-check-if-gpg-pgp-public-key-is-valid)

Comment: Not, it isn't the same in my opinion. I'm using the GnuPG class and I read at the following documentation: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php that if the importation process fails the method will return FALSE, if I put a right pgp my form works fine without any problem, but if I entered a fake pgp my form just throws 502 bad gateway, I want control this kind of error but I don't see how check if the pgp is a correct pgp or not @Oxi

Comment: Sounds like gnupg_import() works correctly and your script simply runs havoc when a non valid key is provided. It'll be best if you show some of your code.

Comment: I updated my question with my code @maxhb

Comment: How is PHP interfaced? See your web server's log files _why_ you get a bad gateway error message.

Comment: I'm using Ngnix (1.4.6) with Ubuntu, and my php version is the following: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 And my nginx error log files throw the following: `recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST pgp.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/pgp.php"` I tried to change listen to "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock to 127.0.0.1:9000 and 127.0.0.1:9002 to see if it coudl fix the problem, but I'm getting the same error yet @JensE

Comment: Seems like the connection is dropped unexpectedly. Anything referring to a crash/core dump in `dmesg` or your system log?

Comment: Yes, I have the following lines at my dmesg: `[ 9861.997823] init: php5-fpm main process (18768) terminated with status 78
[ 9861.997830] init: php5-fpm main process ended, respawning
[ 9862.044614] init: php5-fpm main process (18776) terminated with status 78
[ 9862.044621] init: php5-fpm respawning too fast, stopped
[ 9866.642806] php5-fpm[14454]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f3cfd61a4fa sp 00007ffd4a023b10 error 4 in gnupg.so[7f3cfd614000+a000]
` But I don't know the meaning of them @JensErat

Comment: Some memory access violation happens. This is a bug somewhere in PHP or GnuPG. How did you install GnuPG and the PHP module? It is well possible the versions don't quite fit. For deeper analysis, I fear the next step would be attaching a debugger and digging deeper into the problem -- something far beyond the scope of this site. Make sure you installed everything through your system's package manager, then you should at least not have any troubles with differing versions.

Comment: I just install them installing first the libraries, some of them wasn't availables through my package manager and I download and compile them. And after I installed gnupg executing `sudo pecl install gnupg`  and adding the extension to my php.ini Then, do you recommend me that I install all with a clean installation in another unix version like debian? Thanks @JensErat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error 502 "Bad Gateway" indicates that the connection between the web server and something behind it got interrupted -- this happens for example when using nginx together with php-fpm, which is accessed throughout another network connection/socket. In the comments requesting further debug information you confirmed that guess, and also realized php is crashing because of a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), which means some invalid memory location should have been accessed.

This can either happen because of a bug (which I wouldn't expect in this case, as an invalid key is not some completely surprising input nobody would test for) or because the compiled versions do not really fit together. You explained you build some parts on your own.

Debugging this is a hassle and often takes hours and hours, you'd need to attach a debugger and realize what's going wrong. If you have any chance, try to install everything from the package manager of your choice, do not use different sources like PECL and your packager manager to prevent problems. In Debian (and very likely also Ubuntu and other distributions, I didn't verify) some package like `php5-gnupg` should be available:

```
$ apt-cache show php5-gnupg
Package: php5-gnupg
Source: php-gnupg
Version: 1.3.6-1
Installed-Size: 84
Maintainer: Debian PHP PECL Maintainers <pkg-php-pecl@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: phpapi-20131226, php5-common (>= 4.4), libc6 (>= 2.4), libgpgme11 (>= 1.2.0)
Description-en: wrapper around the gpgme library
 This extension provides methods to interact with gnupg.
[snip]
```

Comment: Sorry for bother you again... I moved to Debian, installed nginx, php etc And if I execute `$ apt-cache show php5-gnupg` it doesn't show me nothing, I searched the php5-gnupg into Synaptic but it doesn't show me any package with that name. I downloaded the package from my browser and I installed php5-common and lipgpgme11, but I don't know how install phpapi-20131226 and when I execute `$ dpkg -i php5-gnupg_1.3.3-1+b1_amd64.deb` that it requires phpapi-20131226 Could you guide me a little? Thanks again @JensErat

Comment: Which Debian version have you installed? The [package is available since Debian 8 (Jessie)](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5-gnupg), which is the current stable release.

Comment: Ohh shit, I have Debian 7.8... Should I can install it without problems if I do it in Debian 8 then? @JensErat

Comment: You might be able to add the Jessie/stable repository and install the packages from there (that's something lots of people do on their desktops, basing on stable and pulling packages from testing/experimental), but expect some fiddles sometimes with dependencies. Is there anything stopping you from performing an upgrade to 8?